# Аккордеон раскрывающееся при наведении

Tags: javascript

Я сейчас работаю над аккордеон, сделал по нажатию, но потом сказали переделать под наведение, матаюсь около часа-двух, но решения не нашёл. Код js прикреплю.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
var i;

for(i = 0; i < acc.length; i++){
    acc[i].onclick = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("äctive");

        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы им скажите, что по наведению плохо будет работать на мобильных устройствах. И оставьте по нажатию))

Comment: onmouseover вместо onclick

Comment: Спасибо! Всё так легко оказалось)